# How do I match a set of non trivial data to a range of non trivial data?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, associations, matching

I have a piece of data like:

```
data = { 
          occupation: doctor,
          waistSize: 32, 
          height: 67
       }
```

I also have another piece of data that we will call a data range, it looks like:

```
dataRange = {  
               rangeName : rangeOne,
               occupation: [doctor, lawyer, teacher],
               waistSize : {min: 28, max: 40}, 
                  height : {min: 50, max: 70}
            }
```

My question is, how can I find all "dataRanges" that contain "data" quickly and efficiently. I don't necessarily need a complete answer, just some advice on which direction to take. My program will contain several hundred "dataRanges", and I need to be able to find all "dataRanges" that include the variable "data".

The answer I thought of off the top of my head is shown below, but I feel that this is horribly inefficient especially when the amount of fields in "dataRange" will be close to 35.

```
db.dataRanges.find( { occupation: { $elemMatch: data.occupation } }, 
                    { waistSize.min: {$lt : data.waistSize } },
                    { waistSize.max: {$gt : data.waistSize } } ,
                    { height.min: {$lt : data.height} },
                    { height.max: {$gt : data.height} } );
```

Also, eventually we will want to create a system where you have a "matchPercentage", this value will represent how closely "data" falls within "dataRange".

Solution needs to be implemented using node.js and mongodb.

Comment: what language? java? C#?

Comment: I'm using node.js and mongodb, so javascript - and the data will be JSON

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to contain your trivial answer that you're unhappy with.

Comment: You don't need to use `$elemMatch` here (just use `occupation: data.occupation`) and you're missing some colons, but that otherwise looks optimal.

Comment: Thanks alot, Johnny. Do you know if there is a way to find,rank, and return data that comes close to exactly matching dataRange, but doesn't match it exactly?

Comment: Not that I know of, no.